# Clear contents of multiple files in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am working with 3 log files in notepad++.
Is there a way the clear the contents of all three files at once in one or two clicks?

I've searched plugins but couldn't find anything. A macro, from what i've tried, records the activity in the active file, so if i change files it won't record that.

A solution would help me alot, thanks.

EDIT: Also it would be great to save the files once they are cleared.
Isn't there something like batch commands to do in notepad++.
(by the way i also tried batch commands to clear the files but then i get that the file is being used by the system, so i concluded that it's only possible from the text editor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Record a macro (`Macro --> Start Recording`) where you perform the following steps

- Open `Search --> Replace...`
- Select `Regular expression`
- Enter regex `^.*(\r\n)*`
- Clear content of `Replace with`
- Click `Replace All in All Opened Documents`
- Click `Ok` and `Close`
- Click the `Save All` button

Stop the macro recording (`Macro --> Stop Recording`) and save it (`Macro --> Save Current Recorded Macro`). From the save dialog you can assign a shortcut to the macro.

Now you can run this macro at any time with the shortcut you assigned.

I have confirmed that this works on `Notepad++ 6.2.2`. On 5.8.1 however the regex does not work.

Comment: I had to check also ". matches new line". If not checked, I still have to manually remove empty lines (see @ellak comment below)

Answer (score 0):

Open find: Check use Regex..

If you want to clear everything..

```
Find    :^.*$
Replace :(nothing)
```

Click replace in all open documents.

(You could also use this same concept (carefully) with "Find in Files")

Comment: that's great, but i want to press a single button or a combination, not go through all the find process.

Comment: This regex will remove the text in the lines but not the lines themselves so you will end up with a bunch of empty lines in the log files.